# Field permission for content type

Tags: nodes

I need to manage different fields for different roles in a content type. If users enter a value for that field, administrator users can see it but not edit that field; on the same content type, when administrator users fill a field, users can see it but not edit it.

I have used the *Field Permission* module for this.

How can I show all the fields to any user, but control the edit part for different roles?

Comment: Did you try the field permissions module? `https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions`

Comment: Yes @HodbaKhalaf I tried field permissions module and "View own" and "View any" options are checked for all roles, authenticated users will be able to edit, I tried with these permissions but what happens is when editor creates the content type admin fields are hidden only editor fields are visible. So i want to display all the fields of that content type irrespective of role. Only expected role should be able to edit. I had given the permission to "edit any content" on peope>>permission because admin has to access the editor content type and fill admin fields.